# Where can I look up the best ASICS under certain conditions

Tags: asic

I have found a lot of helpful websites showing the best hardware for mining in general. However, is there a list of any kind where I can choose the criteria?

For example: I want an ASIC that has a high hash rate, does not cost over 200 dollars, but I do not really care about power consumption. Or the other way round, I want an ASIC that has a good hash rate, a moderate power consumption but I do not care about the costs.

I could not find any website that provides such services

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bitcoinx.com/bitcoin-mining-hardware/

But you probably don't want to mine...

Comment: What do you mean about this comment ? :) Sry ai am fairly new to this topic

Comment: If you can steal electricity, than mining is profitable. Otherwise, it probably isn't. Be aware that if you're stealing electricity, e.g. from your landlord, they will notice the value you're extracting from them. i.e. if you make $100 of BTC a month mining, they will notice their electricity bill go up by $200 a month and come knocking.

Comment: ah I see - yes ofc - no I do not do that. It is more like a project to let it work with green energy (solar powered etc.)